# eloquent or-query over pivot table

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

i have this 2 models

```
Track
   id
   name
   artist_id

Artist
   id
   name


class Song extends \Eloquent{
    public function artist(){
       return $this->hasOne('Artist','id', 'artist_id');
   }
}
class Artist extends \Eloquent{
    public function songs(){
        return $this->hasMany('Song', 'artist_id', 'id');
   }
}
```

Now i want to realize a search given the search term "happy pharrel".
It is clear to me that i have to search the songs where the name of the Song is "happy" or the name of the artist is "happy" **and** where the name of the song is "pharrel" or the name of the artist is "pharrel".

now i'm wondering how i could do such a query with a condition to the song table and the artist table?

Comment: You need to create join between tables to perform search query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code shows that you have specified relations between your tables / classes -- this is good, but I don't think it necessarily helps in the case of a search. It's an excellent way to keep your syntax clean and also for [eager loading](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#eager-loading), but you'll be better off writing a new query for search terms which need to search different columns on different tables.

I'm thinking something along these lines, inside a controller method called when a user submits his search:

```
$keywords = explode(' ', Input::get('search'));

$results = Song::join('artists', 'songs.artist_id', '=', 'artists.id')
               ->whereIn('artists.name', $keywords)
               ->orWhereIn('songs.name', $keywords)
               ->get();
```

It's fairly simplistic, but should be enough to get you started.

Comment: yeah with eager loading and the easy way of keep code clean its very nice. i just though this coul also be used to search for different attributes. Th solution you posted does not work properly i will post it in another answer if somebody also runs into that :)

Answer (score 0):

as tbuteler answered it's the quickest way to get the results to to a database query.

```
foreach($keywords as $p){
    $songs->where(function($query) use($p){
        $query->where('artists.name',"like", "%".$p."%")
              ->orWhere('songs.name', "like", "%".$p."%");
    });
}
```

if you dont do the where(function($query){...} there is 1 query with many or's but and connection between each "or" part is missing

maybe that helps somebody else later